# Windows 7 : Unable to start bitcoin server using daemon in regtest : bitcoind -regtest -daemon

Tags: bitcoind, windows, regtest, daemon

I am trying to start bitcoin server in regtest mode using `bitcoind -regtest -daemon` command on my windows 7 operating system. Error I am getting is 
daemon is not supported on this operating system.

My bitcoin configuration is:

```
regtest=1
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=password
rpctimeout=30
rpcallowip=192.168.1.1/24
rpcport=8332
rpcconnect=127.0.0.1
rpcssl=1
# OpenSSL settings used when rpcssl=1
rpcsslciphers=TLSv1+HIGH:!SSLv2:!aNULL:!eNULL:!AH:!3DES:@STRENGTH
rpcsslcertificatechainfile=server.cert
rpcsslprivatekeyfile=server.pem

gen=1
keypool=100
paytxfee=0.00001000
```

I am a novice so please bear with me if this is a basic question. Tried multiple times but getting same daemon not supported error.

Comment: Yes, the concept of a daemon (background running process) is not implemented in Bitcoin Core for Windows. Just remove the -daemon from your command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the command line on windows you must type just **bitcoind -regtest** whitout -daemon

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Thanks for your answer, you can help by expanding to include any references to explain your answer.