# Running Bitcoind on Windows 10

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

I'm getting the following error running bitcoind (latest stable, v0.16.0) on Windows 10 Pro x64:

`C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>.\bitcoind.exe -daemon
Error: -daemon is not supported on this operating system`

Anyone know why? According to the official docs it should run on Windows 10.
It's also mentioned [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/61333/running-bitcoind-as-a-service-on-windows-10) but no answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 : Unable to start bitcoin server using daemon in regtest : bitcoind -regtest -daemon](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53069/windows-7-unable-to-start-bitcoin-server-using-daemon-in-regtest-bitcoind-r)

Comment: Just like it says: `-daemon` is not supported on Windows.  The bitcoin.org instructions are wrong to suggest it.  I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/issues/2268).

Comment: I understand the error - the docs are blatantly incorrect on indicating it is.